# laravel: command not found in ubuntu 16.04 how to fix..?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed composer, php and others for Laravel and after installing laravel it says laravel command not found. I have tried to add this path but still not working.

It says `laravel: command not found`.

Here is where composer is installed :

```sh
$ which composer
/usr/bin/composer
```

[image: (terminal screenshot)]

What should I add to the PATH or how to solve the laravel command not found here?

```
  If i run :
  composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel new-site-name
```

then i get

[image]

Comment: Did you move composer to global path? check this https://medium.com/@rgdev/how-to-install-laravel-5-4-on-ubuntu-16-04-from-scratch-quickly-29375e18e7ca

Comment: Please include text in your questions instead of images so that search engines, visually impaired people, and anyone trying to copy/paste an error from the question will have less difficulty.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to askubuntu.com

Answer (score 5):

try this one

First, install the Laravel installer package globally to make the `laravel` command available:

```sh
$ composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Next, make sure global composer packages are in your for `PATH` so the command will be found. You can make the modification to your bashrc file like this:

```sh
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then reload .bashrc to apply the changes, using this command:

```sh
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Now try using the command again to create a new project:

```sh
$ laravel new new-site-name
```

If for some reason none of this works, you can still create a new Laravel project with composer (without using the Laravel installer package):

```sh
$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel new-site-name
```

Comment: still not found. After running the command to edit PATH i am unable to run any command. :(

Comment: @DEBASHISBAIDYA did you type the command, or copy it? If you typed it with `>` instead of `>>`, you might have accidentally overwritten the file instead of appending.

Comment: By putting the composer directory at the front of the path, it might also be overriding other system commands. By adding it last, e.g. `$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` you can prevent this

Answer (score 1):

In my development environment Ubuntu 20.04, I wrote:

`$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`

Everything works fine!

Comment: This actually worked for me.
`composer global require "laravel/installer"`
`echo 'export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`
Laravel command worked after these two steps. Thank you!